# How do you check if & variable is set in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In a directive, where you set a method callback through an arg, say:

```
<my-directive callback='showAlert()' />
```

You can retrieve the variable through the scope setting in the return:

```
scope: {
    callback: "&callback"
}
```

If the callback is not set, eg:

```
<my-directive />
```

The value of $scope.callback is still:

```
$scope.callback():function (locals) {
    return parentGet(scope, locals);
}
```

Is there a good way to check that the callback was not set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way i can think off is to check the attribute parameter for the directive name like

```
link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

   if(attrs.callback) {
       //this attribute has been defined.
   }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that with isolated scope, the parameters are always defined

Answer (score 9):

You can use `&?` insteand of `&`. It will make $scope.callback equal to `undefined` if it is not provided.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me when using `ng-hide="{{reset === undefined}}"` defined as: `scope: { reset: '&?onReset' }`

Comment: I freaking love angular

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, since it works perfectly fine with controllerAs syntax and without using a link function.

Answer (score 1):

Because parameters that are passed to the directive will reside on the directive's scope, I prefer to check for type. Even thought it's defined as expression in the scope configuration:

```
scope: { callback: '&attrName' },
link: function(scope, ...){
    if (typeof scope.callback === 'function') {
        // do my stuff
    }
}
```

that way I always sure I'm getting what I expect.

Answer (score 1):

this approach worked for me:

```
scope: {
  callback: '&callback',
  callbackExists: '@callback'
}
```

Then using the second parameter in the template:

```
<div ng-if="callbackExists">…</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the only method that works for Angular 1.5+ components

Answer (score 0):

use `angular.isUndefined` to check `callback` function

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(scope.callback)) {
        // do something when callback undefined
        return;
    }
    // do something when callback defined
}
```