# Check AngularJS directives & variable is set in an expression

Tags: angularjs

This is an extension of the following question

[How do you check if & variable is set in directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820151/how-do-you-check-if-variable-is-set-in-directive)

Is it possible to check that a variable has been set in an expression within the directives HTML?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" ng-click="callback()" 
    ng-show="isFunction(callback)"></button>
```

In the example above `ng-show` evalutes to `null`, as `angular.isFunction` doesn't exist in the expressions.

I tried defining a local function on the scope that but that always returns true because
callback is always defined as the function:

```
$scope.callback():function (locals) {
    return parentGet(scope, locals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that OP has probably found an answer by now, but I'd the same problem today and this was the only question that regarded this issue.

The simplest solution is to check if an attribute is defined on an element:

```
angular.isDefined(attrs['anAttribute'])
```

This does only check the presence of an attribute, without evaluating the expression.

The thing is that angular does wrap `&` functions with a getter (resulting code is in the original question), which prevents us from using `angular.isFunction` or `angular.isDefined`. This is how it does it (angular 1.3.14):

```
[...]
case '&':
  parentGet = $parse(attrs[attrName]);
  isolateBindingContext[scopeName] = function(locals) {
    return parentGet(scope, locals);
  };
  break;
```

However, if we would pass callback this way:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" ng-click="callback" 
   ng-show="isFunction(callback)"></button>
```

then, in directive link function we could do:

```
scope.callback = scope.callback();
angular.isDefined(scope.callback) // actually works as expected
```

Downside of this approach is that we loose some of the declarativeness of directive api.